# bootstrap-datepicker lacks colums when using it on a mobile

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I have created a website using the bootstrap framework. On this website, I'm using the date-time picker and on a standard monitor, everything looks normal. Now, when viewing the same page on a mobile (Android or Iphone), it seems the date-picker lacks columns - for example, I'm lacking Wednesday and Thursday -  Anyone experienced the same issue ?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Duik datum&nbsp;:&nbsp;</label>
            <input name="date_picker" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo(date("d-m-Y", time())); ?>" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```